# "Android is Updating" on every boot

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, dalvik

On every bootup I get the "Android is updating" (Optimizing apps) screen.
I've tried a few methods. I deleted all custom odex files in `/data/app` dictionary and deleted the dalvik cache but it's still there on every boot up. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: did you try to wipe user data ?

Comment: No I would like to avoid that and find another solution.

Comment: what's you device? are you on some official firmware or did you flash a custom rom?

Comment: Samsung Glaxy SM-G350 on stock 4.2. Rooted and Modified with Xposed, but the issue came weeks after modifying my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Cache partition wont write correctly - might be damaged.

Rooted? TWRP?

latest twrp's have fsck (disk check)

Else wise, I have no idea what ur runnin.

Comment: I have root and I have a custom CWM.
Any idea how to tell if that's the case with the cache partition?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the dalvik cache which is broken however you can try to reinstall your ROM flash the Google apps if you want to. Then wipe the dalvik cache, you might want to wipe it before reinstalling your ROM

Comment: I checked my dalvik cache and everything seemed fine. No errors detected.

Comment: Reinstall the rom

Comment: That's the problem. I customised the stock ROM myself and I don't have any flashable ROM files, just a backup. But when I install the backup, I'll have the same problem again.